# What directory does FileOutputStream write to by default on Android

Tags: java, android

I am working on android app in which I am using below code to copy file from asset. The code is working fine but I want to know where it is creating new file.

```
try {
    AssetManager am = getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = am.open("key.p12");
    File file = createFileFromInputStream(inputStream);

    credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(TRANSPORT)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
            .setServiceAccountId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file )
            .build();
} catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

private File createFileFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {

   try{
      File f = new File("key.p12"); <--- where it is creating a new file ??
      OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
      byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
      int length = 0;

      while((length=inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
      }

      outputStream.close();
      inputStream.close();

      return f;
   }catch (IOException e) {
         //Logging exception
   }

   return null;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you log the path to the file and see where it is. Probably this is in the cached directory of the app.

Comment: It's in the app private file folder. Reference: http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is being created at `f.getAbsolutePath()`.